Find all $x$ such that $\varphi(x) \equiv 2 \pmod 8$
My first step was to simplify to $\varphi(x) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function.
From there, is there a simpler way to find these values besides having to list all the exhaustive cases of factorization?

Please add the question to your post.

Do you know how to calculate $\phi(n)$ if you know the prime factorization of $n?$

For $x = 4$ or for $x = p^n, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p$ prime and $p \equiv 3 \ mod \ 8, \ n \equiv 1 \ mod \ 2$ or $p \equiv 7 \ mod \ 8, \ n \equiv 0 \ mod \ 2$.

Or $x= 2p^n$ with above properties.

We can separate into cases where ( x ) is prime or ( x ) is a product of primes.
Case when ( x ) is prime:
Let ( x = p ), where ( p ) is a prime number.  φ(x) is given by:
$$
\phi(p) = p - 1.
$$
So, setting up the equation:
$$
p - 1 \equiv 2 \mod{8} \implies p \equiv 3 \mod{8}.
$$
All the prime numbers that satisfy this condition are of the form $$p=8k+3$$

Case when ( x ) is a product of primes:
(a) Let ( x = p^{k})
So $$\phi(p) = p^{k- 1}(p-1).$$
If (p = 2), then  $$2^{k-1} \equiv 2 \mod{8}.$$ k must be 2 and the only one solution is 4.
$$2^2 = 4 \equiv 2 \mod{8}.$$
Lastly, it is need to analyze the cases where

2
and
x is a product of
k generic primes.

Ok, but my answer is not complete...

First, treat the case of odd $x$. Of course $x>1$. It is easy to show that if $x$ has $r$ distinct odd prime factors then $2^r \mid \varphi(x)$. Hence, as $v_2(\varphi(x)) = 1$ ($\varphi(x) = 8n+2$) then $x$ must be a prime power. Let $x=p^k$ then. If $k$ is odd, then $k-1$ is even so $p^{k-1}$ is a square (or $=1$), which is $1 \mod 8$. Hence  $$\varphi(x) = p^{k-1}(p-1) \equiv p-1 \equiv 2 \mod8.$$ Hence the prime $p$ is of the form $p=8m+3$. If $k$ is even, we get $$\varphi(x) = p^{k-1}(p-1) = p^k - p^{k-1} \equiv 1-p\cdot p^{k-2} \equiv 1-p \equiv 2 \mod8,$$ that is $p = 8m -1$. If $x$ is even, then by previous observation, $x=2^r \cdot p^k$ where $r \geq 1, k \ge 0$ and $p$ is an odd prime. In this case we get $$\varphi(x) = 2^{r-1}p^{k-1}(p-1)$$ and by the 2-adic valuation of $\varphi(x)$, we either have $r=1$ so $x=2p^k$ with the same properties of the odd case, or $r=2$. In the later case, $\varphi(x) = 2p^{k-1}(p-1)$. We then require $$\varphi(x) = 2p^{k-1}(p-1) \equiv 2 \mod 8$$ or equivalently $$p^{k-1}(p-1) \equiv 1 \mod 4.$$ Again distinguish between odd and even $k$, knowing that the residue of a square modulo $4$ is either $1$ or $0$ - If $k$ is odd - $p-1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ so $p= 4m +2$ which cannot be. For even $k$, if $k \neq 0$ then  $1-p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ or $p \equiv0 \mod 4$ which again cannot be. Hence $k=0$, so $x=4$. To summarize, the solutions are $x=p^k = (8m+3)^k$, $x= 2p^k = 2(8m+3)^k$ for odd $k$ or $x=p^k = (8m-1)^k$, $x = 2p^k = 2(8m-1)^k$ for even $k$ or $x=4$.

You forgot the case $2p^k$ with $p>2$ with the appropriate conditions (see my comment above).

@psl2Z Thanks, I'll add this.
